# New child class or conditional read from same one?

Tags: java, oop, refactoring

Lets say I've a class:

```
class Foo{
    datatype1 x;
    datatype2 y;
    datatype3 z;
}
```

I want to populate:

1. x if y = a
2. z if y = b

That is, Foo with constructor would look like:

```
class Foo{
    datatype1 x;
    datatype2 y;
    datatype3 z;

    Foo(x, y){
        // x and y are intialized
    }
    Foo(z, y){
        // z and y are intialized
    }
}
```

y is initialized to support decision making in the future of the object i.e. depending on value y, I'll read x or z.

Does it makes OOP's sense to extend Foo and do this:

```
class Bar extends Foo{
    datatype1 x;
}

class Zar extends Foo{
    datatype3 z;
}
```

and then instantiate Bar if the condition that used to make y equal a is met and Zar if the condition that used to make y equal b is met. Which means I will use instanceof on Bar's or Zar's object to do whatever I used to do earlier after reading y.

What I find ugly: Object of Foo will either have x intialized or z depending on y. The field left uninitialized will have default value (null or its equivalent). Its a see-saw like condition, always!

Comment: Could you please show us some code where you use this object after the construction? Currently it's unclear. Probably it's even better to have two completely unrelated types.

Comment: Would you consider an [Either](https://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/Either.html) as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to model and the relationships. As Tagir wrote it also depends on what the client code look like.

Foo, Bar and Zar convey zero meaning to me, so it is hard to recommend anything.

Do you just use Foo, Bar and Baz to hold data or do they have other methods than getters?